# chol(x,pivot=TRUE) does not have attribute pivot in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

If I run the code below, `xStep1` does not have an attribute named pivot. According to the doc's it should have this attribute. Any help would be appreciated.

```
x=Diagonal(10000)
x[1,3]=0.3
x[3,1]=0.3
xStep1=chol(x,pivot=TRUE)
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used `R` but from memory one of the nice things was you can type the function name into the interpreter (i.e. `chol`) and it'll dump out the code. I always found that an easy way of checking what the parameters were. Maybe you have a different version (or you've loaded a package that has the same function with a different signature)

Comment: Thanks. Here it what that outputs: standardGeneric("chol")
chol
standardGeneric for "chol" defined from package "base"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("chol")
<environment: 0x000001932a70e188>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods(chol)  for currently available ones.

Comment: Note that `chol` from base, require the input matrix to be symmetric  your `x` matrix is not.

Comment: Do the examples from the documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.5-3/topics/chol) work?

Comment: The matrix is clearly symmetric! Just run isSymmetric(x)

Comment: I tried with one of the examples. It did return pivot. But that example is using a small matrix.

Comment: It seems like Cholesky(A=x,perm=TRUE) contains what I need!

Comment: The docs for [`chol`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chol.html) for dense matrices mentions returning pivot info as an attribute but there is no mention in the dcos for [`sparse matrices`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/chol.html) (which you use in your example). Are you using another package, and if som can you show the docs.

Comment: `class(x) == "dgCMatrix"`, and running `chol` on a `"dgCMatrix"` object dispatches `Matrix:::chol`. Accordingly see `?Matrix:::chol` for options.